# TextBloB: correct() method returning empty object

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, textblob

I am trying to use [TextBlob's spelling correction](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/quickstart.html#spelling-correction), but correct() returns with an empty object for every call.
The following shows the method call on the terminal:

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob
>>> b = TextBlob("I havv goood speling!")
>>> b.correct()
TextBlob("")
>>> print(b.correct())

>>>
```

I am running Python 2.7.6 on Linux.

Comment: Same results on Windows, Python 2.7.8

Comment: I also posted this issue on their Github repository. [Here](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/99) is the link, in case anyone wants to track it.

Comment: I don't get the error on Python3.4. It's apparently just a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bug in `TextBlob` after their latest update. Here are my results before (`v 0.9.0`) and after (`v 0.10.0`) I update the TextBlob package (I am using Python `2.7.10`):

Result from `TextBlob 0.9.0` :)

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob, __version__
>>> __version__
'0.9.0'
>>> b = TextBlob('I havv good speling!')
>>> b.correct()
TextBlob("I have good spelling!")
```

Result from `TextBlob 0.10.0` :(

```
>>> from textblob import TextBlob, __version__
>>> __version__
'0.10.0'
>>> b = TextBlob('I havv good speling!')
>>> b.correct()
TextBlob("")
```

**UPDATE:**

The bug is [now fixed](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/99#issuecomment-152771151).

Comment: Yes, I raised the issue on their repo, so that the devs could solve it soon. It started working properly after I updated the package. Thanks.

Comment: how can i add custom data or corpus to textblob ? so that it can do spell check right . @Aziz Alto